# jQuery pushState load content, different URLs

Tags: jquery, json, pushstate

I encountered some problems when I tried to recreate a demo from http://html5.gingerhost.com/. I will try to describe the situation as clear as possible:

On my page there is  < a href="index"> which when is clicked it triggers:

- a pushState event that changes the URL bar of the browser into **mysite.tld/index**
- a getJSON call that loads a random url and put it instead of the current < a href="index">

When the user click the loaded random url, the pushState event does not trigger and the browser follows the random url... which is not what I want. I want to continue triggering the pushState event and to continue loading random urls.

Something like this:

- CLICK INDEX

  - LOAD INDEX2 and REPLACE INDEX

    - CLICK INDEX2 *(here it breaks. it loads the real page)*

      - LOAD INDEX3 and REPLACE INDEX2 *(here I want to arrive)*

I apologize if I'm not clear. I'm not very confident on my jQuery skills.

Do you have any suggestions?

Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function(e) {
            href = $(this).attr("href");

            loadContent(href);

            history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    function loadContent(url){
        $.getJSON("load.php", {pid: url}, function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(key, value){
                $(key).html(value);
            });
        });         
    }   
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <a href="index">Go to: index</a>
    </div>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**load.php**

```
<?php $i = rand(0,10); ?>
{
"div":"<a href='<?php echo $_GET['pid'].$i; ?>'>Go to: <?php echo $_GET['pid'].$i; ?></a>",
"p":"This is the page for <?php echo $_GET['pid']; ?>"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because

```
$('a').click(function(e) { …
```

only works on the `a` elements that are in the DOM at the point of execution of this line. You replace it with *another* `a` element later, which does not get caught by this.

Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead, f.e. like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e) { …
```